# Fatal error: Class 'SelectQuery' not found in /*/includes/database/database.inc on line 813

Tags: 7, database

My site works fine in local system, Upload code and database in server show Error.

Fatal error: Class 'SelectQuery' not found in /*/includes/database/database.inc on line 813

Answer (score 0):

Check database setting in settings.php file. If database configuration is right then just clear the cache and rebuild registery.